# EXEC different queries based on different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 conditions, based on each condition I need to run a separate query.  Something like this:

```
Declare @p1 varchar, @p2 varchar, @p3 varchar, @q1 varchar, @q2 varchar , @q3 varchar


set @p1 = 'type'
set @p2 = ( select top 1 from myTable where column = '8')
set @p3 = '1234'

set @q1 = ' select * from foo ' 
set @q2 = ' select * from foobar '
set @q3 = ' select * from reallyfoobarred ' 


if @p1 = @p2  // if this is true execute query 1 
begin
EXEC (@q1)
end 
if @p1 = 'fish' // if this is true execute query 2 
begin 
exec (@q2)
end 
if @p1 = 'cats' // if this is true execute query 3 
begin 
EXEC (@q3) 
end
```

The problem is the variables have to be re-declared and set for each query.  Is there some way to do this with only declaring the variables once? Where I am at now is thinking about 3 separate stored procs. I don't want to do that if I don't have to.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Re-declare what variables?

Comment: yeah so if the first condition is not met I get a "must declare variable" error.

Comment: The example given isnt really clear enough to show what you are really wanting to do, as the example queries dont show any need of parameter handling etc. I'd recommend you show the real queries instead. However, on the basis of what you've got now, I guess you could put your statements into a table, keyed by the key value of each condition, then use a single stored proc to retrieve the appropriate statement into a variable which is then executed.

Comment: So I am loading a dropdownlist. I need to load specific items based on a variety the user selects. So I need to run a different query based on what the user selects.

Comment: Question is still very vague.  I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should handle the logic of which query to run inside your application, when the user selects from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
declare @par varchar(10)

set @par = ( select top 1 variety from myTable)

if @par = 'CATS'
select all_cats from myOtherTable
else if 
@par in ('Birds','Fish')
select not_dogs from myOtherTable .........
```

And so on. Thank you for your help everybody. I thought about doing it this way when I got home last night.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring the size for the `varchar` and your values get truncated.

Declare your variables like

```
Declare @p1 varchar(100), @p2 varchar(100), @p3 varchar(100), 
        @q1 varchar(100), @q2 varchar(100), @q3 varchar(100)
```

See demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7215e/44) - I have modified it and commented out your table names. This should give you the idea.

```
Declare @p1 varchar(100), @p2 varchar(100), @p3 varchar(100), 
        @q1 varchar(100), @q2 varchar(100), @q3 varchar(100)


set @p1 = 'type'
set @p2 = ( select top 1 'type' ) --from myTable where column = '8')
set @p3 = '1234'

set @q1 = ' select ''foo query''' --* from foo ' 
set @q2 = ' select ''foobar query''' --* from foobar '
set @q3 = ' select ''reallyfoobarred query''' --* from reallyfoobarred ' 


if @p1 = @p2  --// if this is true execute query 1 
begin
EXEC (@q1)
end 
if @p1 = 'fish' --// if this is true execute query 2 
begin 
exec (@q2)
end 
if @p1 = 'cats' --// if this is true execute query 3 
begin 
EXEC (@q3) 
end
```

This will print `foo query`